# Tensorflow always returns nan

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm creating a neural network in tensorflow, and my output is always nan. I'm not completely sure what this means, but I've heard that it means that the problem is something like log(0). I can't really find anything like that in my code though. Here is my code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

all_data = pd.read_csv('/projects/first-repository/train.csv')
all_data = all_data.values

layer1_size = 4
layer2_size = 20
layer3_size = 1

data = np.stack([all_data[:, 2], all_data[:, 5], all_data[:, 6], all_data[:, 7]])
data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data, np.float32)
labels = all_data[:, 1]
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, np.float32)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, [891, 1])

theta1 = tf.get_variable('theta1', shape=(layer2_size, layer1_size), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
theta2 = tf.get_variable('theta2', shape=(layer3_size, layer2_size), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

a1 = data
z2 = tf.matmul(theta1, a1)
a2 = tf.nn.relu(z2)
z3 = tf.matmul(theta2, a2)
a3 = tf.nn.softmax(z3)
h = tf.transpose(a3)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=h))
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1):
        sess.run(train)
        print(sess.run(cost))
```

I've tried to replace h with h+1e-4, and the output didn't change. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check that there is no nan in your data to start with...

Comment: You can use tf.debugging.check_numerics to find out where the nans come from. tf.debugging.check_numerics(x) returns x unchanged, except it will give an error if x contains a nan. So just apply it to each tensor in the graph until you find the point at which you get nan (which could be already in the input as Julien says).

Comment: @tomkot I tried it and returned an error, saying that the message was missing. I looked it up, and saw that the message was another part of the command, but I couldn't find much. How does the message argument work?

Comment: You probably found this out already, but for posterity's sake -- I got it wrong before, tf.debugging.check_numerics(x, message) receives two arguments, where message is the prefix of the error message to be printed in case there are NaN's or Inf's, followed by a message such as "Tensor had NaN values".

Comment: @tomkot I figured out the problem, but I don’t fully understand the debugging command. There were just some nan values in the input data, but how do I use the tf.debugging command exactly?

Comment: This command helps you find where your NaNs are coming from. If the NaNs are in your input, then that's the answer, and you have to deal with them. But another option would have been that you don't have NaNs in your input, but some tensor operation creates them. For example, if you have some very large or very small weights, the answers of operations could be Infs and 0s, and multiplying them could lead to NaNs.